# Javascript Async Loops

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous

Still wrapping my head around Javascript's asynchronous nature. Help me understand this: I have several functions that need to be run on items in an array.

We have Option 1:

```
for (f of files){
  do_a(f);
  do_b(f);
  do_c(f);
}
```

vs Option 2:

```
for (f of files){
  do_a(f);
}

for (f of files){
  do_b(f);
}

for (f of files){
  do_c(f);
}
```

1. Which would be faster?
2. In option 1 would the do_b function fire even if do_a is still working?
3. In option 2 would the do_b loop fire even if do_a loop is still working?

Comment: Javascript is single threaded - meaning functions cannot fire while another is still working, unless the other is interrupted or temporarily releases control. If the functions that operate on the elements do not interfere with one another, option 1 is better. Especially on files, where cache misses could play a considerable role.

Comment: **1.** I'd say option 1 since you're only looping once. **2.** yes, if `do_a` is asynchronous. **3.** yes, if `do_a` is asynchronous.

Comment: Unless the functions themselves are asynchronous, this question isn't about JavaScript's asynchronous nature, just performance.

Comment: And what exactly is asynchronous here?

Comment: Based on the comments I'm gathering that Javascript is synchronous unless explicitly specified as asynchronous (ie, in how the function is defined)?

Comment: Note that for e.g. `function f() { setTimeout(otherFunc, 100); }`, when called, `f` will execute to the end but maybe you will consider what `otherFunc` does to be part of it. But strictly speaking, it is a different func and `f` completed although `otherFunc` did not yet.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @guest271314 A better understanding of Javascript, programming, loops and how they all interrelate?

Comment: There is no conclusion to understanding. Is there a specific problem that you are trying to solve? Given the descriptions and code that you provided, have your questions been sufficiently answered?  You have yet to answer @Bergi 's inquiry as to what is asynchronous within the code that you posted? What is expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is not clear
2. Yes, the function will be called
3. No, the first loop would complete before second loop begins

Comment: Just to clarify on #3: the loop would be completed, but the `do_a` functions in it might still be running if they are asynchronous

Comment: By "it's not clear" I assume you mean that's dependent on the nature of the functions... But all things being equal (lets say each function takes exactly T time to finish) would 3 loops each taking Tx1 time be faster than 1 loop taking Tx3 time?

Comment: @blex That is a matter of how the pattern is constructed. Even if the call is asynchronous, the next loop can be composed to wait until the first loop completes

Comment: @Trees4theForest "It is not clear" is based on the facts at Question. "faster" is left undefined. No current benchmarks appear at Question for the approaches. It would be speculation to state which approach would be "faster" - run the tests to get the accurate results

Answer (score 1):

1. Which would be faster?

It's hard to say.

2. In option 1 would the do_b function fire even if do_a is still working?

While Javascript supports asynchronous programming the code you have presented here is completely synchronous and so the functions will do work in the order you have written them.

3. In option 2 would the do_b loop fire even if do_a loop is still working?

No, for the same reason.